# I need to check performance of desktop application via j meter tool. How can i record steps in desktop application ? Please guide

Tags: jmeter

As for web based application with the use of proxy settings we can record. How recording can be done for Desktop applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter cannot be used for desktop applications. You can use it to simulate network traffic between your app and the server. In short, you will be testing only the server response times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Is there any tool to check server response time for desktop application ?

Comment: You need to setup a Proxy server that measures the server performance. There is Charles - https://www.charlesproxy.com/ which can help you do this. You can also use Jmeter https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf